# Find all the index adjacent to the given index in a NxN board

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose I have a 10x10 cells board. The index for each cell is from 1 up to 100 (1-based index). The board is a list of cells: `[1, 2, 3, ..., 100]`.

Task. Given an index of a cell, find all the cells that cover it.

For example:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
_____________
5 | 6 | 7 | 8
_____________
9 |10 |11 |12
_____________
13|14 |15 |16
```

Given index: `11`

Returns: `[6, 7, 8, 12, 16, 15, 14, 10]`, order is not a concern.

My solution for this:

```
def allAdjacentCell(given_index):
    result = []
    dimension = 4 # length of a line
    if (1 <= given_index - dimension <= 16):
        result.append(given_index - 1) # the cell above the given cell
    if (1 <= given_index + dimension <= 16):
        # below given index
    if (1 <= given_index - 1 <= 16):
        # ...
    if (1 <= given_index + 1 <= 16):
        # ...
    # check for diagonal cells
    return result
```

If the given cell is at somewhere in the center of the board, my method seems to return the correct result. But if the given cell is at the corners or the edges, it's wrong. For example, if given cell = 5, then the method will include the cell at index 4, although it's not adjacent to 5.

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: How is your board represented? A single list? A list of lists?

Comment: Yes, it is a single list. I included it in the question, thanks very much.

Comment: This is called the Moore Neighbourhood.

Comment: This would be much easier, if your indeces started at `0`

Comment: I'll change the based then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more pedestrian version of the answer given by Willem Van Onsem, in which I explicitly convert between your indices and easier to handle coordinates. I also included a test to check if everything works as intended:

```
dimension = 4

def label_to_coords(label):
    x = (label - 1) % dimension
    y = (label - 1 - x) // dimension
    return x, y

def coords_to_label(x, y):
    return x + dimension * y + 1


def allAdjacentCell(given_index):
    result = []
    x, y = label_to_coords(given_index)
    for delta_x in range(-1, 2):
        for delta_y in range(-1, 2):
            if not (delta_x == delta_y == 0):
                new_x = x + delta_x
                new_y = y + delta_y
                if (0 <= new_x < dimension) and (0 <= new_y < dimension):
                    result.append(coords_to_label(new_x, new_y))
    return result

def test():
    size = dimension**2
    for i in range(1, size + 1):
        print(i, allAdjacentCell(i))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Answer (score 2):

We notice that we get 'rougue' values only when the index value is in the right most or left most column or top or bottom rows.

Top/bottom rows rogue values are only negative or out of bound values.

For an index in the left most column rogue values would have %dim=0.

For an index in the right most column rogue values would have %dim=1.

Thus we only need to filter them out from the standard value of an index in the centre.

```
def all_adjacent(index,dim):
    arr = [index+1,index-1,index+dim,index-dim,index+dim+1,index+dim-1,index-dim+1,index-dim-1]
    if index%dim==0: ## right most row
         arr = filter(lambda x:x%dim!=1,arr)
    if index%dim==1: ## left most  row
        arr = filter(lambda x:x%dim!=0,arr)

    arr = filter(lambda x:x>=1 and x<=dim*dim,arr)  ## top and bottom rows

    return arr
```

Comment: This is the approach described in [Bradhurst et al. (2016)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364815215301043) for calculating the Moore neighbourhood.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if it is an *edge*-case (for instance `5`), then `5-1` is still a valid index (but not an adjacent one). You can solve this by first determining the `x` and `y`:

```
x = (given_index-1) % dimension
y = (given_index-1) // dimension
```

There is no need to make it that hard: you know that the result should be between `0` (inclusive) and 15 (inclusive). You can use a nested `for` loop:

```
result = []
for nx in (x-1,x,x+1):
    if 0 <= nx < dimension:
        for ny in (y-1,y,y+1):
            if 0 <= ny < dimension and (nx != x or ny != y):
                result.append(ny*dimension+nx+1)
```

You can even put it in a nice *one-liner*:

```
x = (given_index-1) % dimension
y = (given_index-1) // dimension
result = [ny*dimension+nx+1 for nx in (x-1,x,x+1) if 0 <= nx < dimension for ny in (y-1,y,y+1) if 0 <= ny < dimension and (nx != x or ny != y)]
```